# 2d histogram: Get result of full nbins x nbins

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, histogram2d

I am using matplotlib's hist2d function to make a 2d histogram of data that I have, however I am having trouble interpreting the result.

Here is the plot I have:

[image]

This was created using the line:

```
hist = plt.hist2d(X, Y, (160,160), norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=20))
```

This returns a 2d array of (160, 160), as well as the bin edges etc.

In the plot there are bins which have a high frequency of values (yellow bins). I would like to be able to get the results of this histogram and filter out the bins that have low values, preserving the high bins. But I would expect there to be 160*160 values, but I can only find 160 X and 160 Y values.

What I would like to do is essentially filter out the more dense data from the less dense data. If this means representing the data as a single value (a bin), then that is ok.

Am I misinterpreting the function or am I not accessing the data results correctly? I have tried with spicy also but the results seem to be in the same or similar format.

Comment: Why would you expect `160 x 160` values? Isn't that all of your histogram?

Comment: @QuangHoang perhaps I misunderstand, but shouldn't there be 160 bins in the x-axis and then 160 bins in the Y axis, for each of the X bins? So every Xbin should have 160 Ybins?

Comment: Yes, that’s your original histogram, I.e. the picture you plotted. But didn’t you want to filter just the high density bins?

Comment: yes, I'd like the histogram as arrays so that I can filter the results after plotting. But I can only find 160 X and 160 Y bins, but shouldn't the full histogram have 25,600?

Comment: I’m not sure I followed. You stated clearly hat you get a `160 x 160` array. That is you me histogram, is it not? The functions returns only the edges of `x` and `y`, which is 161 each. You can make the cross product of the edges to get the 2D bins, if that’s what you’re asking.

Comment: Yes, I think I may have confused myself. I'll put it this way, what I would like is the frequency value for any bin in the histogram. So, for example, how would I get the frequency of the bin that is 100 bins in the x direction and 100 bins in the y direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted.

[The hist2d docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) specify that the function returns a tuple of size 4, where the first item `h` is a heatmap.

This `h` will have the same shape as `bins`.

You can capture the output (it will still plot), and use `argwhere` to find coordinates where values exceed, say, the 90th percentile:

```py
h, xedges, yedges, img = hist = plt.hist2d(X, Y, bins=(160,160), norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=20))

print(list(np.argwhere(h > np.percentile(h, 90))))
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed in order to index the right bins in the X and Y direction!

Answer (score 0):

You need [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) package.

You mentioned

> I would like to be able to get the results of this histogram and **filter out the bins that have low values, preserving the high bins**.

You should **definitely** be using one of those:

1. `seaborn.joinplot(...,kind='hex')` : it shows the counts of observations that fall within hexagonal bins. This plot works best with relatively large dataset.
2. `seaborn.joinplot(...,kind='kde')` : use the kernel density estimation to visualize a bivariate distribution. I recommed it better.

#### Example 'kde'

Use number of levels `n_levels` and `shade_lowest=False` to ignore low values.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
x, y = np.random.randn(2, 300)
plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
sns.kdeplot(x, y, zorder=0, n_levels=6, shade=True, cbar=True, 
     shade_lowest=False, cmap='viridis')
```

[image]